# How many solutions of any given triangle (SSA) are there using the sine law?

Tags: trigonometry

How can you tell how many solutions a triangle will have, given SSA? In addition, how can each solution be verified?

Comment: I do not know how" rigorous" it has to be, but this site may be of some help: http://www.softschools.com/math/calculus/the_ambiguous_case_of_the_law_of_sines/

Comment: Without any proof, the following holds: Let the measurements be $a$, $b$ and $\alpha$. If $a \geq b$, then there is always exactly one solution. If $a < b$ and $\alpha$ is obtuse we have no solution at all. If $a < b$ and $\alpha$ is acute, then we have 0, 1, or 2 solutions depending on whether $a/b$ is larger or smaller than $\sin\alpha$.

Comment: @imranfat Thanks, anything helps. +1

Comment: Actually, there are so many examples on the internet. They put examples with 1 triangle, 2 triangles and no triangles "side by side". The idea is to apply Law of Sines assuming that one triangle exists. Once you find and angle from the arcsine, you subtract this angle from 180 and see if a second triangle can be formed. You can generalize it with algebra pertaining sides $a,b,c$ and angles $A,B,C$ but I also found that to be a pain. My advice, examples, examples, examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say in $\triangle ABC$, we have $m\angle A$, $a$, and $c$. Now, draw the altitude from $B$ and say it hits $\overline{AC}$ at $D$. Solve for $BD$ using the fact that $\triangle ADB$ is right with right angle $m\angle D$. Now, compare $BD$ with $a$:

- If $a < BD$, then that's impossible because $BD$ is the leg and $a$ is the hypotenuse of $\triangle BDC$, so it makes no sense that the hypotenuse is shorter than the leg. At this point, you automatically stop because you know that all of the solutions you get will be wrong.
- If $a=BD$, then $D=C$ and $\triangle ACB$ is actually a right triangle with right angle $m\angle C$. This means the congruence relation is actually hypotenuse-leg and there is only one possible solution. You don't need Law of Sines here because you can just use the Pythagorean Theorem.
- If $a > BD$, then we have two possible solutions because [$m\angle C$ could be acute](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/36700/36740/tri19_36740_lg.gif) or [$m\angle C$ could be obtuse](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/36700/36739/tri18_36739_lg.gif). Here, we use Law of Sines and make sure that we don't get any negative angles. Any solution sets with negative angles are wrong and we throw them out.